# How can I maximize my trophy/achievement collection in Dragon Age: Awakening?

Tags: dragon-age-origins, achievements, dragon-age-origins-awakening

I'm playing through *Dragon Age: Awakening*, and I'd like to maximize my trophy collection while minimizing my play-throughs.

Is it possible to get all the trophies in one play-through? Are there any gotchas, things to watch out for, or save points I should be aware of?

To give a few examples from *Dragon Age: Origins* of the type of things I'm thinking of:

- Saving before each mutually-exclusive "faction" decision can allow you to get the trophies for each choice
- Three strategic save points at the end of the game allows you to get the *Perfectionist* trophy and all of the ending trophies with only an hour of backtrack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might as well answer my own question. All trophies are easily gotten by completing the main story line, except for the following:

#### Missable:

> **The Enduring Vigil**: Make sure you get the [Silverite Ore](http://dragonage.wikia.com/wiki/Silverite_Ore) while at the Silverite Mine, as you can't return to it later.

#### Mutually Exclusive:

> **Amaranthine's Last Hope** and **Keeper of the Vigil**: Make sure to save when the Darkspawn invade Amaranthine so you can get one trophy, then reload to get the other.